# Почему не работает якорь в мобильной версии и плавный скролл?

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал якоря, ничего не могу понять, почему они не работаю при приямом заходе по ссылке. При перезагрузке ссылки с якорем он срабатывает, при прямом заходе нет.... В чем может быть проблема? Плавный скролл кстати тоже почему-то не хочет работать.

В ссылке пробовал "#имяякоря" и "/delivery/#имяякоря" - все равно не работает при загрузку страницы в мобильной версии.

Конструкция:
Ссылка:

```
<a href="/delivery/#world_delivery">Доставка по России</a>
```

Якорь:

```
<a name="world_delivery" id="world_delivery" class="scroll"></a>
```

Ссылка на страницу с проблемой:
https://mishka-furs.webtm.ru/delivery/

Кстати скрол плавный (сделан через стили) работает почему-то после перезагрузки с якорем... При прямом заходе на ПК резкий переход по якорям....

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить `scroll-behavior: smooth` на прокручиваемый контейнер

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился, в теме создавалось два контейнера, один для моб, другой для ПК, оба контейнера скрывались за счет display none в результате чего получался конфликт этих якорей. Переименовал якоря и все заработало.